# Is this an example of a javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Still feel my understanding of Javascript closure is a little woolly at times and I would like to know if the code below represents closure in action...

```
function StateManager () {
    var self = this;

    this.state = null;

    $(document).on("internal_StateManager_getState", function () {
        return self.state;
    });

    $(document).on("internal_StateManager_setState", function (e, p) {
        if ( p && p.state ) {
            self.state = p.state
        }

        return self.state;
    });
};

new StateManager();

alert( $(document).triggerHandler("internal_StateManager_setState", { "state": 88 }) );
```

Is it accurate to say that this demonstrates closure because the state and self variables are accessable via the events? Thanks for any input!

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the "class", there are actually several closures in that code, jQuery creates a closure for each callback etc. when the `self` variable is accessed that way (outside it's lexical scope).

Comment: Yes - the "class" is what I meant :)

Comment: The way the code is written, without any context etc. the class itself is not really a closure because it doesn't refer to variables outside it's lexical scope, so no.

Comment: FWIW, theoretically every function in JavaScript is a closure, because every function has access to the variables defined outside of it.

Comment: [`state` is not a variable, but a *property* of the `this`/`self` object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code in the question, the `StateManager` function does not create a closure, as it doesn't reference "free" variables from outside it's lexical scope.

However the jQuery callbacks are in fact closures, as they do reference the `self` variable which is defined outside the lexical scope of the callback functions.

A closure is, from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables.
>
> In other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created.

A simple example would be something like

```
function something() {

    var test = "Hello Kitty"; // "test" is a local variable created in this scope

    function otherFunc() { // this is an inner function, a closure
        alert( test ); // uses variable declared in the parent function
    }

}
```

That's about as simple as closure gets, it's just a function inside another function that uses variables outside it's lexical scope.

Another familiar example would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // creates outer scope

    var data = 'important stuff';

    $('.elems').on('click', function() { // this is a closure
         $(this).text( data ); // uses variable outside it's scope
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for that adeneo - it's the end of the work day for me but I will sleep on what you have said and see if it is all clear tomorrow :)